# Are there any limitation to the number of posts for a certain period?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Are there any limitation to the number of posts for a certain period? Suppose, I want to ask more than six questions within one hour. Does this act go against the rules of this website? What is the highest number of questions which can be asked within one hour?

Comment: Please don't think like this. Such posting will be appreciated by no-one, not even the most kindhearted among us. It has been done before. By asking low-quality questions at the maximum permissible rate, it means that you don't respect the culture of this site. It would be like me throwing my candy wrappers on your home's floor while I was a guest there; it just shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 9):

We do have [a limit](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/do-we-want-to-enable-post-limits), but it's based on a number of days not hours: six questions per day, and fifty per month. So you would be allowed to submit six questions in an hour, but that would use up your allowance for the day.

That said, six questions an hour should be infeasible, unless they are of poor quality. Take a look at [an answer about question quality and research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043). Even six questions a day should be pushing it.